# The conditions for when user wins for slot machine isnt working properly

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a slot machine game in c# where if all 3 slots match, the user wins 2x their bet and if 2 of the slots match, then the user wins their bet back and if none of the slots match then the user losses their bet but sometimes when there are 2 slots that match, the user doesnt win their money back and sometimes when there are no slots that match, the user wins their money back and sometimes when the user gets 3 matches, they win their money back but not double. How do I also make it so that if all 3 slots have a jackpot image, the user wins 5x their bet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;

namespace Slot_Machine
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int a, b, c, move, wins,losses, bid;
        int balance = 100;

        private void QuitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void ResetBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Restart();
        }

        void Before_Game_Result()
        {
            bid = Convert.ToInt32(BidAmountTxt.Text);
            balance = balance - bid;
            BalanceLbl.Text = "Balance: $" + Convert.ToString(balance);
        }

        void Game_Result()
        {
            if (System.Convert.ToInt32(a) == b && System.Convert.ToInt32(b) == c)
            {
                wins++;
                WinLbl.Text = "Wins: " + wins;
                bid = Convert.ToInt32(BidAmountTxt.Text);
                balance = balance + (bid * 2);
                BalanceLbl.Text = "Balance: $" + Convert.ToString(balance);
                BidBtn.Enabled = true;
                BidAmountTxt.Enabled = true;
                BidAmountTxt.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            else 
            {
                if ((System.Convert.ToInt32(a) == b && System.Convert.ToInt32(b) != c) || (System.Convert.ToInt32(a) == c && System.Convert.ToInt32(b) != c) ||
                (System.Convert.ToInt32(b) == c && System.Convert.ToInt32(a) != c))
                {
                    wins++;
                    WinLbl.Text = "Wins: " + wins;
                    bid = Convert.ToInt32(BidAmountTxt.Text);
                    balance = balance + bid;
                    BalanceLbl.Text = "Balance: $" + Convert.ToString(balance);
                    BidBtn.Enabled = true;
                    BidAmountTxt.Enabled = true;
                    BidAmountTxt.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    losses++;
                    LossesLbl.Text = "Losses: " + losses;
                    BalanceLbl.Text = "Balance: $" + Convert.ToString(balance);
                    BidBtn.Enabled = true;
                    BidAmountTxt.Enabled = true;
                    BidAmountTxt.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
            

            if (balance <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You don't have any money!! SCRAM");
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void BidBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(BidAmountTxt.Text =="")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("input a bid first!!");
            }
            else
            {
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(BidAmountTxt.Text);
                bool success = false;
                if(x <= balance)
                {
                    success = true;
                }

                if(success)
                {
                    Before_Game_Result();

                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                    BidAmountTxt.Enabled = false;
                    BidBtn.Enabled = false;
                    BidAmountTxt.BackColor = Color.Black;

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("INVALID - please enter a bid lower or equal to your balance");

                    BidAmountTxt.Clear();
                }



            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            move++;
            if (move < 30)
            {

                a = rnd.Next(5);
                b = rnd.Next(5);
                c = rnd.Next(5);
                

                switch(a)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Slot1.Image = Properties.Resources.basketball3;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Slot1.Image = Properties.Resources.soccer_ball2;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Slot1.Image = Properties.Resources.volleyball;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Slot1.Image = Properties.Resources.hockey_puck;
                        break; 
                     case 4:
                        Slot1.Image = Properties.Resources.Jackpot;
                        break;
                }
                switch (b)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Slot2.Image = Properties.Resources.basketball3;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Slot2.Image = Properties.Resources.soccer_ball2;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Slot2.Image = Properties.Resources.volleyball;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Slot2.Image = Properties.Resources.hockey_puck;
                        break;
                     case 4:
                        Slot2.Image = Properties.Resources.Jackpot;
                        break;
                }
                switch (c)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Slot3.Image = Properties.Resources.basketball3;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Slot3.Image = Properties.Resources.soccer_ball2;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Slot3.Image = Properties.Resources.volleyball;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Slot3.Image = Properties.Resources.hockey_puck;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Slot3.Image = Properties.Resources.Jackpot;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                    move = 0;
                
                    Game_Result();
                   
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `System.Convert.ToInt32(a)` etc, when the variables `a`, `b` and `c` are already declared as `int`? Unfortunately you've provided a lot of code but not much information about the circumstances in which things go wrong. If you could provide sample values of `a`, `b` and `c`, the expected result and the actual result, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably you are ignoring one valid return value of [`rnd.Next(5)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-7.0#system-random-next(system-int32)). Ie, you ignore, that `Next` may also return `0`. Thus, if for one of `a`, `b` or `c` you have a value of `0`, you don't change the image. Thus on the screen you may see a winning situation where there is none or vice versa ...

So change your switches for `a`, `b` and `c` to

```
switch(a) {
  case 0: ... 
  case 1: ...
  case 2: ...
  ...
}
```

to also deal with a value of `0`. And either introduce an additional symbol or change your random function to `rnd.Next(4)` to return values from `0`..`3`

But there are also some other remarks about your code

1. `System.Convert.ToInt32(a) == b` does not make any sense, as all of `a`, `b` and `c` are already integers. You can simply compare `if (a == b)`
2. When checking your "2-matches" winning situation `(System.Convert.ToInt32(a) == b && System.Convert.ToInt32(b) != c)` you don't need to check the inequality of `b` and `c` because at this position in the code you already know, that not all three values are equal (because otherwise your code would have entered the `a==b && b==c` branch. Thus if `a == b`, `c` must be different. No need for checking it again. Same of course for all other "2-matches" checks.